# App doesn't run after change Excel Dll

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2013

i have an old project in VS2013(desktop app in vb), wich included the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll, in version 12. But i had removed it and i added the version 14 of the same dll. The problem, when i build and publish the app, it doesn't run in windows 10, showing me an Exception where the app can not create the Activex Object. I had notice with the change, that the application files in the publish section, had changed. With version 12 the dll was include, but with the update, i can not see a reference in that section.

Hope you could give me lights about this problems

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the reference in Solution Explorer, choosing Properties, and setting Copy Local to True?

Comment: It works, now i can see a reference in the Publish section, but when i run the app in the final device, i got the same error... The app can't create the Activex Object. Any suggest my friend?